Implication & usage for the following lemma: a monomial $x^\beta \in I$ iff $x^\alpha\mid x^\beta$ for some $\alpha\in A\subset {\Bbb{Z}^n}_{\geq 0}$
The following are partly taken from Malik and Sen's Fundamentals of Abstract Algebra,
Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms
An Introduction to Computational Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra by Cox, Little and O'SHea,
and
Algebraic and Geometric Ideas in the Theory of Discrete Optimization by Loera, Hemmecke and Kopppe.
Background
Lemma:  Let $I=\langle \{x^\alpha\mid\alpha\in A\} \rangle$ be a monomial ideal.  Then a monomial $x^\beta \in I$ if and only if $x^\alpha\mid x^\beta$ for some $\alpha\in A$.
(Note: $A\subset {\Bbb{Z}^n}_{\geq 0}$)

Proof: If $x^\alpha\mid x^\beta$, then there exists $h_\alpha\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ such that $x^\beta=h_\alpha x^\alpha\in I$  Suppose $x^\beta\in I$.  Then $x^\beta=\sum_{i=1}^{q}h_i x^{\alpha(i)}$, where $h_i\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $\alpha(i)\in A$.  Now $h_i=\sum_{j=1}^{m_1}k_{ij} x^{\beta(ij)}, k_{ij}\in K$. for all $i,j$.  Thus $x^\beta=\sum_{i=1}^{q}(\sum_{j=1}^{m_i}k_{ij} x^{\beta(ij)})x^{\alpha(i)}$ and so $x^\beta=\sum_{i=1}^{q}\sum_{j=1}^{m_i}k_{ij} x^{\beta(ij)+\alpha(i)}$.  Hence $\beta=\beta(ij)+\alpha(i), j=1,\ldots,m_i$; $i=1,\ldots,n$ except for thoe $i$ and $j$ which drop out when like terms are combined.

Example 1: $J=\langle x^4y^2,x^3y^4,x^2y^5 \rangle$
$\alpha+{\Bbb{Z}^n}_{\geq 0}=\{\alpha+\gamma
\mid \gamma \in{\Bbb{Z}^n}_{\geq 0}\}$
$((4,2)+{\Bbb{Z}^n}_{\geq 0})\cup((3,4)+{\Bbb{Z}^n}_{\geq 0})\cup((2,5)+{\Bbb{Z}^n}_{\geq 0})$
Example 2: Let us decide whether $f=x^4-z+y$ belongs to $I=\langle x^3y,x^2z,x^2 \rangle, x^4$ is divisible by $x^2$ while $z$ is not divisible by any monomial generator of $I$.  Thus $f$ is not in $I$.
Questions
For the above lemma, I am a bit confused as in what context is useful, also I had to search far and wide for an example illustrating the lemma.  I had two questions above the lemma.
$1)$ Can the lemma be used to find generator for the ideal $I$ stated in the lemma (or $J$ in the case of example 1 above).  There is no reason why a-priori that $x^\beta\in I$ and also that the $\alpha$ required in the lemma can't be the same $\alpha$ for each element of the ideal $I$. In Example 1 above, I can simply let $\alpha=(2,2)$ for each time $\beta\in \{(4,2),(3,4),(2,5)\}:$
$x^\beta=x^4y^2=x^2y^2\cdot x^2y^0$,
$x^\beta=x^3y^4=x^2y^2\cdot xy^2$,
$x^\beta=x^2y^5=x^2y^2\cdot x^0y^3$,
so that $\langle x^2y^2 \rangle=\langle x^4y^2,x^3y^4,x^2y^5 \rangle$, with $x^\alpha=x^2y^2$
$2)$ as example 2 above is an illustration of how the lemma can fail, is the above lemma another way of solving the ideal membership problem.  I know that later on in the theory of Grobner bases, there is the method of determining a Grobner bases as part of the method for determining whether elements of an ideal belong to another ideal.  In what circumstances would the above lemma be an inadequate tool for solving the issue of ideal membership problem.
Thank you in advance

What are you indicating with $A$ and $\mathbf{W}^n$? Every monomial ideal is finitely geneted, so $A$ should be a finite set of $n$-uples of positive integers.

@Hola I edited my post.  $W*^n$ equals to ${\Bbb{Z}^n}_{\geq 0}$. I don't understand if the theorem is stating that it can be used to find the generator of the ideal $I$ stated in the theorem or why it is needed to show that if element from another ideal belongs to the ideal $I$ compare to finding a suitable grobner bases of the ideal $I$.

I didn't get your example... you take $\alpha=(2,2)$, but $x^2y^2\notin J$ and, moreover, it is false that $⟨x^2y^2⟩=⟨x^3y,x^2z,x^2⟩$.
That Lemma is a simple property to describe the set of monomials which belong to an ideal $I$. Your Lemma can restated in this way, maybe it can help you to see it from another perspective.
Lemma. Let $I$ be a monomial ideal and ${u_1, \dots, u_m}$ be a monomial system of generators of $I$. Then a monomial $v$ belongs to $I$ if and only if there exists a monomial $w$ such that $v = w u_i$ for some $i=1,\dots,m$.

@Hola I edited my post.  It should be $\langle x^2y^2 \rangle=\langle x^4y^2,x^3y^4,x^2y^5 \rangle$.  In your equivalent rephrasing, the $v$ you stated, is it comes from anther ideal not in $I$, or is the lemma about how $v$ relates to the system of generators ${u_1,\ldots, u_m}$ via the relation $v=wu_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$? Also why is this lemma necessary when I can simply just find a grobner basis for the ideal $I$ to see if $v\in I$?

The $v$ that I stated is a generic monomial in $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. The Lemma expresses a necessary and sufficient condition in order that a generic monomial $v$ belongs to an ideal $I=(u_1,\dots,u_m)$.
To address your second question, I’m not entirely sure what you’re referring to, as each book tends to have its own approach to explaining Gröbner bases.

@Hola oh ok ok.  Basically if I have a $v \in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, and I want to know if it belongs to the ideal $I$.  That makes more sense.  My second question has to do with using grobner bases to resolve the ideal membership problem.  I am wondering how the lemma is different from simply finding à grobner base comparé to this lemma.
